# "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 2" with flutter carousel

Tags: json, flutter, carousel

The *imageList* list contains image paths extracted from a JSON file. However, this issue is encountered only once but disappears after hot reload.
Package used: carousel_slider: ^3.0.0

Code:

```
CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          height: 250.0,
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          reverse: false,
                          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                          autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
                          autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                          pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        ),
                        items: imageList.map((img) {
                          return Builder(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10.0,
                                  horizontal: 10.0
                                ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                ),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  img,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your imageList is empty at first and when you're filling it you're not calling setstate() and if you are it means the carousel doesn't let you use an empty list
add an if statement this would make it so that the carouselSlider isn't built if the list is empty

```
if(!imageList.isEmpty)
  CarouselSlider()
```

Comment: Hi. I used the setState(). It works fine now. Thanks

Comment: @newbie maybe mark my answer as accepted?